# need perl one liner to get a specific content out of the line and possibly average it

Tags: perl, shell, unix, command-line

I have a file which had many lines which containts "x_y=XXXX"  where XXXX can be a number from 0 to some N.

Now,
a) I would like to get only the XXXX part of the line in every such line.
b) I would like to get the average

Possibly both of these in one liners.

I am trying out sometihng like

```
cat filename.txt | grep x_y | (this need to be filled)
```

I am not sure what to file
In the past I have used commands like

```
perl -pi -e 's/x_y/m_n/g'
```

to replace all the instances of x_y.
But now, I would like to match for x_y=XXXX and get the XXXX out and then possibly average it out for the entire file.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to perl and regexes.

Comment: There were a couple good solutions. Could you please the one you like most as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 6):

Timtowtdi (as usual).

```
perl -nE '$s+=$1, ++$n if /x_y=(\d+)/; END { say "avg:", $s/$n }' data.txt
```

Comment: +1: by far the best way, unless the OP has multiple `=` in a line as he has hinted when it would need to be changed to `$s+=$1, ++$n while /x_y=(\d+)/g`

Comment: @Borodin I love the `while` suggestion. Gosh, Perl is fun (in small snippets).

Answer (score 3):

The following should do:

```
... | grep 'x_y=' | perl -ne '$x += (split /=/, $_)[1]; $y++ }{ print $x/$y, "\n"'
```

The `}{` is colloquially referred to as *eskimo operator* and works because of the code which `-n` places around the `-e` (see `perldoc perlrun`).

Comment: `perl -F/=/ -ane '$x += $F[1];...`

Comment: does this assume that there is only one '=' in the line? Or that this is the first '='. Will this work if the line has "a_b=yyyy b_z=uuuu x_y=XXXX" going to check anyway and will update.

Comment: I assumed that it's only `x_y=XXXX` on this line, at the point where I split `$_` on `/=/` and then extracted the second element (zero-based index `[1]`) from the result of `split`. For multiple space-delimited assignments, you can do `/x_y=(\S+)/ or next; $x += $1` instead of the `$x += ...` expression in the original answer. That will even save you the `grep`.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk:

```
/^[^_]+_[^=]+=[0-9]+$/ {sum=sum+$2; cnt++}
END {
    print "sum:", sum, "items:", cnt, "avg:", sum/cnt
}

$ awk -F= -f cnt.awk data.txt
sum: 55 items: 10 avg: 5.5
```

Pure bash-solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='=' read str num
do
    if [[ $str == *_* ]]
    then
        sum=$((sum + num))
        cnt=$((cnt + 1))
    fi

done < data.txt

echo "scale=4; $sum/$cnt" | bc ;exit
```

Output:

```
$ ./cnt.sh 
5.5000
```

Comment: A few suggestions: `IFS='=' read str num` to restrict the change to the `read` command's environment. I think `x_y` was a pattern for the variable names, not a literal string; `if [[ $str == *_* ]]` (or just `?_?`) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner, split up with comments.

```
perl -nlwe '
    push @a, /x_y=(\d+)/g          # push all matches onto an array
    }{                             # eskimo-operator, is evaluated last
    $sum += $_ for @a;             # get the sum
    print "Average: ", $sum / @a;  # divide by the size of the array
' input.txt
```

Will extract multiple matches on a line, if they exist.

Paste version:

```
perl -nlwe 'push @a, /x_y=(\d+)/g }{ $sum += $_ for @a; print "Average: ", $sum / @a;' input.txt
```